# VBA - how to use macro button for multiple boxes

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and macro. I will try to explain what I am trying to create then I will explain what problem I have with it.

There are two sheets in my Excel; 'Sheet 1' and 'Sheet 2'.

Sheet 1 is full of data. This data goes from column A to AK and there are 4206 rows.

Sheet 2 only consist an input cell box with a 'GO' button next to the box. The button is assigned to a macro.

**What do I want to create?**

In the input cell box I type something like 'GB' and then press the 'GO' button. The 'GO' button will look through Sheet 1 for cells with 'GB' in them. There are two particular columns that could have 'GB' in them; one of them is column K and one is column L. The 'GO' button will look in those two columns for 'GB' and filter the rows.

Important note: I don't want to design a macro so that they will look for 'GB' in column K ***and*** column L. Instead I want them to look for 'GB' in column K ***or*** column L.

**What did I create?**

I designed a macro and assigned it to the 'GO' box. This is the code that I put in:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    Range("A12:AM4216").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("A1:AK2"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

**What works with the code? And what is the problem?**

The code will return rows that has 'GB' in column L. This is great. However, I am looking of ways how to change the code so that it will return rows that has 'GB' in column K ***or*** column L.

Any advice on this please?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about using the filter for this, but I have done a workaround where I loop through the cells using IF cells(i,1)="X" OR cells(i,2)="X" THEN 'Nothing_when_true Else Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True End IF.  Just unhide all rows on each button press before looping.

Comment: Apologies, but I am not clear on this. Are you saying that use IF statement instead of using VBA/Macro?

Comment: The macro would contain a loop (For i = start TO end) with an if statement inside that hides the row if it doesn't meet the criteria.  It pseudo-filters by hiding rows, but doesn't give the other benefits of true filtering, such as sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should probably do it. I was a little confused on whether the 'GB' was something that would vary or if it would be the same every time, so I included the option for both (by default the code assumes it's static). I also didn't know if you wanted it case-sensitive, so by default, it is NOT case sensitive (to make it case-sensitive, remove the `LCase` functions).

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim firstCol As String, secondCol As String
Dim findStr As String
Dim x As Long

'define worksheet to check
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'or whichever sheet

'define search string to check for based on static value
findStr = "GB"

'define search string to check for based on cell value
'findStr = ws.cells("A1") 'or whichever cell

'define start and end rows to loop through
firstRow = 12
lastRow = 4216

'define columns to check
firstCol = "K"
secondCol = "L"

'turn off screenupdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'unhide rows in range
ws.Range(ws.Rows(firstRow).EntireRow, ws.Rows(lastRow).EntireRow).Hidden = False

'loop through the rows
For x = firstRow To lastRow
    'if either cell has the search string in it (regardless of case)...
    If InStr(LCase(ws.Range(firstCol & x)), LCase(findStr)) Or InStr(LCase(ws.Range(secondCol & x)), LCase(findStr)) Then
        '...do nothing
    Else
        '...otherwise, hide the row
        ws.Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next x

'turn screenupdating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    

End Sub
```

Please note that like Cyril mentioned above, this is not a true filter: it just hides rows that don't match the specified criteria.

Comment: You will also need Sheets("NAME").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False before the subroutine works.  This should be executing on a button press, so we would want to avoid just hiding all rows in the end, with multiple searches.  You could also make ws.Rows(x).EntireRows.Hidden=False rather than unhiding the entire worksheet.

Comment: Good point. Taking that one step further, you could just un-hide the rows in the specified range with `ws.Range(ws.Rows(firstRow).EntireRow, ws.Rows(lastRow).EntireRow).Hidden = False`, so added that in.

Comment: Hello everyone,

Thank you for this! Really helpful.